# What is this sheet of clear stickers that came with a new MTB?

Tags: mountain-bike

I just ordered a new MTB through the mail (Santa Cruz Bronson). In the spare parts and accessories bag was this weird sheet of heavy vinyl clear stickers. I can only assume they are for frame protection or something? But I can't really figure out where they fit, and the fact that the two "hook" shaped ones aren't mirror images seems odd to me. I doubt I need then for anything... this is more just idle curiosity at this point, thanks!

[image]

Comment: I think the round ones are to stop your cables rubbing against the frame and normally go near the cable lugs.

Comment: I'm guessing the two hook ones are for the right chainstay, for chain slap protection.  The round ones will be to protect the frame from rubbing of a cable outer, and the long oval one probably goes on the top tube, between the exposed inners and the frame, again to protect the paint.     If you want to use these, put them on now, before the frame gets even a little scratched.  Also they'll stick better when new, and when the frame is not oily.   Not an answer because I'm guessing.

Comment: Criggie is correct; it's best to fit them now if at all, since the frame is clean and free from oil.  If you fit them later, you'll have to buff the frame thoroughly before applying, ideally with isopropanol (rubbing alcohol) to remove grease/oil.  Even finger prints can prevent these from sticking properly.  I also find that heating the frame and/or patch with a hairdryer helps them stick.

Comment: Why don't the manufacturers apply the frame protection stickers themselves? Seems odd to leave it up to the customer to figure it out.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These are protective stickers for the chainstay, bottom end and some spots on your frame where the brake and speed cables cause frictions with the frame, scratching the colour.

Comment: And if you intend to use them (which isn't a bad idea), apply them now, while the bike is clean (and unscratched).

Comment: (But note that it may be a generic sheet -- for several different bikes.  Some of the pieces may not fit anywhere sensible.)

Answer (score -1):

I didn’t know they were to protect the frame from cables. I used mine as an extra security device. I washed my hands, touched the sticky side with different fingers and stuck them to the bike. Now my fingerprints are permanently hidden on the bike frame to prove that it’s mine if my bike gets stolen. It works.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. This site does not operate like a typical forum. It operates on a Q&A basis. This is not an answer in as much as it is a constructive comment to the other answer (that actually answered the question). So this should be a comment applied there, not as an additional answer.  Please only use the "answer" button to answer the OP's question. Once you have asked and answered a few questions, you'll have earned enough [reputation](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) to [comment everywhere](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) on the site.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/56444)